# media image rendered by django template broken

Tags: html, django, broken-image

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [...#'django.contrib.staticfiles',]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

my_app/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^welcome/', views.upload, name='upload'),] + 
static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

my_app/templates/template.html

```
<img src='media/my_image.jpeg'>
```

my_app/views.py

```
def upload(request):
    if request.METHOD == 'POST:
    ...
        return redirect(to another page)
    return render(request, 'template.html')
```

The template.html renders correctly, but the image is broken.

When I tried

```
curl -D - http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_app/welcome/media/my_image.jpeg
```

I get a 200 and when I go the welcome URL in the browser the backend returns

```
[22/Mar/2018 13:31:57] "GET /my_app/welcome/ HTTP/1.1" 200 411
[22/Mar/2018 13:31:57] "GET /my_app/welcome/media/my_image.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 200 411
```

so I don't think it's a url problem. Chrome is showing images. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your regex is missing a `$`, so it matches not only `/welcome/` but also `/welcome/media/my_image.jpeg` (that's why your `curl` command returns status code 200). Change the URL pattern to:

```
url(r'^welcome/$', views.upload, name='upload'),
```

Next, you are missing the leading slash to make it an absolute URL.

```
<img src='/media/my_image.jpeg'>
```

Finally, you need to server the media files as well as the static files. [In development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development), you can add the following to your *project's* urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: media exists with the project, so I don't think I want an absolute URL. If I change urls.py in the way you suggest (add $ and add media paths), I get ```[22/Mar/2018 14:33:17] "GET /my_app/welcome/ HTTP/1.1" 200 411
Not Found: /my_app/welcome/media/my_image.jpeg
[22/Mar/2018 14:33:17] "GET /my_app/welcome/media/my_image.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 3143```

Comment: You should be using `static()` in the *project's* urls.py. It's very odd to have it in `my_app/urls.py` - in that case, the URL would be `/myapp/media/my_image.jpg`.

Comment: In retrospect, that makes complete sense. Thank you!